# How do I Create an Entire Web Form along-with its respected Code-Behind(.cs) file in Asp.Net on click of a button?

Tags: asp.net

I Want to create an entire Web-Form on click of a button along with its Code-behind(.cs) file . I can work fairly with Asp.Net but i love to explore new things.just a question that popped up in my mind while working on something new ! So please if anyone of the great minds out there can help please help me out. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for Visual Studio 2013

1. Open your web solution
2. In Solution Explorer, right click the web project
3. Choose "Add Web Form"
4. Enter a name for the form
5. Click OK

See also [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hds5k93.aspx)

Comment: i think OP needs to create the file pair using c#/vb  code and not in VS

Answer (score 0):

Just extend Web Form class, define properties and methods which will render and show your web form. Handle button click event, initiated web form. Finally display it.

If its normal form you can simply render it using jQuery/JavaScript.

Hope this helps you buddy. :)